# git on Azure don't ask me for password, push fails

Tags: windows, git, azure, microsoft-documentation

I am learning Azure, and what I observed, a huge part of the official Microsoft documentation is either obsolete, or doesn't correspond to the reality, or just does not work as expected because of errors.

One example is the article I study, [Create deployment slots (on Azure)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/stage-deploy-app-service-deployment-slots/3-exercise-create-deployment-slots).

Here I am stuck with the following:

[image]

The first question is, what the hell is the "Cloud Shell", I didn't find such a thing in the Azure portal, so I supposed they talk about the `Console` from the `Development Tools` section... OK, lets go :

```
D:\home\demoapp\app-service-web-dotnet-get-started>git remote add production https://myusername@mytestslots.scm.azurewebsites.net:443/MyTestSlots.git

D:\home\demoapp\app-service-web-dotnet-get-started>git push production
Logon failed, use ctrl+c to cancel basic credential prompt.
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://myusername@mytestslots.scm.azurewebsites.net:443': Bad file descriptor
```

So, OK, I am not asked for password!?! What to do?

I tried

```
git config --global core.askpass /usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass
```

but

> error: cannot spawn /usr/libexec/git-core/git-gui--askpass: No such
>   file or directory

tried

```
git config --global core.askpass "C:\Program Files\Git\\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-gui--askpass"
```

but the same

> error: cannot spawn C:\Program
>   Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-gui--askpass: No such file or
>   directory

Please help.

Comment: To use Cloud Shell from Azure Portal, please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/quickstart. HTH.

Comment: why all this is not specified in the learning documentation? As for new people to azure, they just can't know this. Also, it asks me Bash or PowerShell, I have no idea, also it proposes me to mount a storage.. What for, and why should I do this just for learning? Why the Console in the Development Tools is not OK?

Comment: @GauravMantri, now everything worked as expected! thanks a lot. Please add an answer in order me to consider it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question about `Cloud Shell in Azure Portal`, please see this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/quickstart.

Regarding your comments about the quality of the content on Microsoft Learn, you can provide feedback by navigating to the bottom of the page (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/stage-deploy-app-service-deployment-slots/3-exercise-create-deployment-slots) and then clicking on `reporting an issue`. This will redirect you to this [`link`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/support/troubleshooting?uid=learn.azure.stage-deploy-app-service-deployment-slots.3-exercise-create-deployment-slots&documentId=7ff00149-879a-c2c4-aab1-a05cf01eb7ca&versionIndependentDocumentId=f91204f9-f4a2-c0fc-2203-b09b04ef2b92&contentPath=%2FMicrosoftDocs%2Flearn-pr%2Fblob%2Flive%2Flearn-pr%2Fazure%2Fstage-deploy-app-service-deployment-slots%2F3-exercise-create-deployment-slots.yml&url=https%3A%2F%2Flearn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flearn%2Fmodules%2Fstage-deploy-app-service-deployment-slots%2F3-exercise-create-deployment-slots#report-feedback).

You can provide detailed feedback there. In my experience, Microsoft folks are quite responsive to the feedback.

Comment: what about the console, as I mentionned in the OP. Why it didn't work, the password wasn't asked?